# showing 12 items instead of 16 on WordPress / Woocommerce page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

i have a WordPress site using Avada theme, and Woocommerce. The products categories pages will show 16 items at a time. My issue is that the sidebar's existence means the products are 3 in a row, and this causes the last row to only have 1 product. This can lead the user to think there aren't anymore pages.

I need to show 12 items instead of 16, and that will fix me! I am comfortable editing theme files / CSS. I was hoping for insight to the best way. Thanks!

https://paramedsupply.com/product-category/blood-collection/

Answer (score 0):

it was in Avada > Woocommerce settings! I just found it. I had assumed it wouldn't be that easy!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem with other themes and can't seem to override any display settings.

You could declare the following WooCommerce theme support arguments:

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', array(
        'thumbnail_image_width' => 150,
        'single_image_width'    => 300,

        'product_grid'          => array(
            'default_rows'    => 3,
            'min_rows'        => 2,
            'max_rows'        => 8,
            'default_columns' => 4,
            'min_columns'     => 2,
            'max_columns'     => 5,
        ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```